# Could not resolve w/ token 01000060 from typeref(expecte class'Xamarin.Forms.FlyoutPage' in assembly'Xamarin.Forms.Core,Version=2.0.0.0,Token=null

Tags: xamarin

[System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000060 from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.FlyoutPage' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGcl7.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7qN9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGcl7.png)

Hello,
I am making an app on xamarin, and and after adding the FlyoutPage on Xaml and Xaml.cs to make the sliding Menu it's giving me this error.
Can anyone help me please? Thank you..

Comment: Your screenshot cannot show the problem.Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Comment: I solved it. It was the Flyout class that creating the problem. As far as I've eliminated that class the problem was solved. Thank you